# How to see what data inside an SQLite database using PyCharm?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I am beginner in Python,I now using Flask and SQLAlchemy for creating simple database like below:

```
..import all the stuff here

Base = declarative_base()


class Restaurant(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'restaurant'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)


class MenuItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'menu_item'
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    course = Column(String(250))
    restaurant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("restaurant.id"))
    restaurant = relationship(Restaurant)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurant.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I am coming from PHP and MySQL background,so my question is:

I am using PyCharm IDE. I've heard that PyCharm has a built-in functionality to inspect a database. How can I view the contents of the database in PyCharm so that I can inspect the contents of the database visually instead of running queries in a console?

Comment: did you check sqlite browser for sqlite databases ?

Comment: This is not really the right place to ask for development tools, but I've been using Sqliteman for those databases.

Comment: in pycharm just double click your `restaurant.db` and select open as datasource ... you might have to download pycharms sqlite driver (theres a little message at the bottom of select datasource)

Comment: I've edited the question to ask how to do this in PyCharm. A question that asks for a *tool recommendation* is off-topic, but since you're using PyCharm already, I've written it so that Joran's answer fits it and it is no longer off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A story in 5 pictures, that apparently dont count as text, but are really worth 1000 words

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course this is a PyCharm Pro feature, not available in Community Edition!